# How does the stats.gaussian_kde method calcute the pdf?

Tags: python, scipy, gaussian, probability-density

I am using the `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` method from `scipy` to generate random samples from the data.

It works fine! What I have now found out is that the method also has inbuilt functions to calculate the probability density function of the given set of points (my data).

**`I would like to know how it calculates the pdf provided a set of points.`**

Here is small example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
from scipy import stats

def getDistribution1(data):
    kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(data,bw_method=0.06)
    class rv(stats.rv_continuous):
        def _rvs(self, *x, **y):
            return kernel.resample(int(self._size)) #random variates
        def _cdf(self, x):
            return kernel.integrate_box_1d(0,max(x)) #Integrate pdf between two bounds (-inf to x here!)
        def _pdf(self, x):
            return kernel.evaluate(x)  #Evaluate the estimated pdf on a provided set of points
    return rv(name='kdedist')

test_data = np.random.random(100) # random test data 
distribution_data = getDistribution1(test_data)
pdf_data = distribution_data.pdf(test_data) # the pdf of the data
```

In the above piece of code, there exists three methods,

1. `rvs` to generate random samples based on data
2. `cdf` which is the integral of the pdf from 0 to max(data)
3. `pdf` which is the pdf of the data

The reason I need this pdf is because now **I am trying to calculate weights** for my data based on probability. **So that I can give each of my data point a probability which I can then use as my weights.**

I would also like to know from here how I should proceed to calculate my weights?

P.S. Forgive me for asking the same question in cross validated, there seems to be no response!

Answer (score 0):

The online docs have a link to the source code, which for `gaussian_kde` is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/stats/kde.py#L193

Comment: Thanks for the source code, but what I don't understand from it is that, I have a 1D array, and there the `evaluate` function is doing it only for a 2D array! But I am getting some pdf for my data! How is it so? I am confused!

Comment: there's an `atleast_2d` call right in the beginning. In general, best ask an actual, separate question.