# How to assign weights to a set of variables based on pdf?

Tags: python, scipy, probability-density

This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186868/how-does-the-stats-gaussian-kde-method-calcute-the-pdf) to which I had another doubt and was asked to ask a new question! So here goes.

Say I have an array of size 100.

How do I calculate the probability of each of the value in the array?

My understanding so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def getDistribution(data):
    kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(data,bw_method=0.07)
    class rv(stats.rv_continuous):
        def _rvs(self, *x, **y):
            return kernel.resample(int(self._size)) #random variates
        def _cdf(self, x):
            return kernel.integrate_box_1d(0,max(x)) #Integrate pdf between two bounds (-inf to x here!)
        def _pdf(self, x):
            return kernel.evaluate(x)  #Evaluate the estimated pdf on a provided set of points
    return rv(name='kdedist')

data = np.random.random(100)
sorted_data = np.sort(data)

dist = getDistribution(sorted_data)
pdf = dist.pdf(sorted_data)

plt.plot(sorted_data,pdf_data,'-o')
plt.hist(sorted_data,normed=True)
plt.show()
```

**I know that the above code gives me the pdf** and when plotted alongside the histogram of my data, I get something like this. [image]

**I would like to know how I can get the probability on each of my points that belong to the data.** I want to assign the same as the weights to each of my data points.

Comment: This question is statistically problematic. `I would like to know how I can get the probability on each of my points that belong to the data.` - The probability of what exactly?
KDE is one way to get an estimation of the probability density of the distribution that generated the sample. Note that you cannot get the exact density, you can only estimate it. And as always in life, there's not just one choice. There are several density estimators and all make some assumptions you better check before you apply them.

Comment: @cel: `The probability of what exactly?` Given a set of 100 points within 0 and 1, the probability of, lets say, finding a particular value or in other words since this is a not a discrete case, the relative likelihood of getting that value. **When I calculate the `pdf`** using the above method on my data set, the example being random numbers within 0 and 1, **what am I actually getting?** I am not generating a distribution of my data using KDE here.

Comment: `the relative likelihood of getting that value` - relative to what? To a random model? Yes you can do that. Just calculate the ratio of the two likelihoods. You can consult wikipedia to find out why this makes sense.
I think the problem here is, that the question "what is the probability of observing a specific value" is not a meaningful question in the continuous case. If you want to ask that, you can start discretizing and ask instead: "what is the probability that I observe a value between a and b". This question is meaningful and can be answered by integrating the pdf from a to b.

Comment: @cel: doesn't the `kernel.integrate_box_1d(0,max(x))` in the code above do the integration that you saying? Can I use this to get the probability of observing a value between a and b?

Comment: No, the code does not do the integration from a to b. The code calculates the cumulative density function. Yes, you can use the cumulative density function to calculate the probability of observing a value between a and b. CDF(b) - CDF(a).

Comment: @cel: Thanks for your valuable advice. One final question, so for the probability of observing a value between a and b, I can use the CDF as mentioned in your above comment, right? and if I do so for all of my values, I should sort of get the sum of my CDF to be 1?